# Disable a GWT Grid

Tags: java, gwt

OK, I have a GWT DataGrid as

```
DataGrid<T> grid
```

and now I want to disable it so that the user can't scroll it or mess around with it an any way. Is there a way to do that?

It doesn't implement setEnabled() so I would have to provide my own implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using CSS as

```
getElement().getStyle().setProperty("opacity", "0.6");
getElement().getStyle().setProperty("pointerEvents", "none");
```

and when enabling again do

```
getElement().getStyle().setProperty("opacity", "1");
getElement().getStyle().setProperty("pointerEvents", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

When a UI element is disabled, it looks different - this is a good principle of UI design. When you say "disable" DataGrid, it's not clear how you are going to communicate to a user that it is disabled. For example, the scroll bars will remain visible, the headers will look clickable, etc.

The only solution that comes to mind is to cover the DataGrid with a semitransparent popup panel (aka "glass"). It will consume all user actions, and thus it will prevent any interaction with a DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to prevent the user from doing weird stuff on your grid, maybe you can catch the event and call the method preventDefault

For Example

```
dataGrid.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Comment: Good idea. I did that and it appears to fire, but it doesn't prevent any clicks. I also added a ScrollHandler and it appears to never fire.

Comment: if you want to prevent scrolling, this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997130/lazy-load-data-in-a-gwt-datagrid) will help you to retrieve the scrollPanel of your datagrid and add a scrollHandler to it

Comment: Ok, the scrollhandler fires, but does nothing to prevent scrolling.

Comment: strange, did you try event.getNativeEvent().preventDefault() ?

Comment: Tried it with the same result (i.e. it fires, but prevents nothing).